# How do I get the value of a input number type?

Tags: javascript, jquery

if i have

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="nama" name="nama" value="blabla">
```

I can get value by

```
var v_nama = $('input:text[name=nama]').val();
```

but if I have

```
<input type="number" min="0" class="form-control" id="jmlh" name="jmlh" value="4">
```

jQuery cant do this

```
var v_jmlh = $('input:number[name=jmlh]').val();
```

I got warning : **Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: number**

so how I can get the value of a input number type ??

Comment: Both of those `input` elements have `id` attributes, select by that instead.

Comment: `$('input[name=jmlh]').val()`. You can easily find out which selectors are supported by reading the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: `var v_jmlh = $('input[type=number][name=jmlh]').val();`

Comment: Selecting by `id` is the fastest way so use it.

Comment: Selecting by `id` is the fastest way so use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've to use attribute selector as jQuery doesn't specially provide pseudo-selector `:number`

```
var v_jmlh = $('input[type=number][name=jmlh]').val();
```

But anyway, since you've the `id` assigned, you'd be better off using `$('#jmlh')` as it's the fastest way using jQuery.

Comment: @Vinsens glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Use type as JQuery attribute

```
var v_jmlh = $('input[type=number][name=jmlh]').val();
```